# Find the infinite sum of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \ \frac{1}{(2n)!}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \ \frac{n}{2^n}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need help with this problem:

> Find the following infinite sums. (Most of the cases are equal to $f(a)$ where 
>   $a$ is an obvious number and $f(x)$ is defined by a power series. To calculate the series, it is necessary to effect the necessary arrangements until there appear some well-known power series.)

1. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \ \frac{1}{(2n)!}$
2. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \ \frac{n}{2^n}$

For the first one, I really don't know how to begin.
For the second one, I started by rewriting it like: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \ n(\frac{1}{2})^n$ so it looks like a geometric series; after that I don't know what to do. Is it ok if I divide it by n and end up with $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \ (\frac{1}{2})^n=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=2$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\cosh(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(2n)!}z^{2n}}$. So, $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(2n)!}}=\cosh(1)$$

For the second, if $|z|<1$, then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{z^n}=\dfrac{1}{1-z}$, I suppose you know that. Therefore, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{nz^{n-1}}=\dfrac{1}{(1-z)^2}\implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{nz^{n}}=\dfrac{z}{(1-z)^2}$$ Now, take $z=\frac{1}{2}.$

I will explain the first sum using exponential. We have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(2n)!}}$, each time you see factorial is a good idea think in exponential series. So, note that in this series you have only "even factorials", So I'll try to form this series. Note that $$e^{x}+e^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}x^{n}}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}(-1)^{n}x^{n}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}x^{n}(1+(-1)^n)}$$

Clearly, the terms $1+(-1)^n=\{0,2\}$ if $n$ is even or odd number. so, we only considered the even numbers, i.e., $$e^{x}+e^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}x^{n}(1+(-1)^n)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{2}{(2n)!}x^{n}}$$

You can see that this looks a lot like the series we are looking for. Now take $x=1$ in the above,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(2n)!}}=\frac{1}{2}(e^{1}+e^{-1})$$

And using the complex form, $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$, you can see $$e^{1}+e^{-1}=e^{i(-i)}+e^{i(i)}=(\cos(-i)+i\sin(-i))+(\cos(i)+i\sin(i))$$
$$=(\cos(i)-i\sin(i))+(\cos(i)+i\sin(1))=2\cos(i)$$
And we "define", $\cos(i)=\cosh(1)$. Finally, $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(2n)!}}=\frac{1}{2}(e^{1}+e^{-1})=\cos(i)=\cosh(1)$$

Comment: How do you know that? I had no idea that $\cosh(x)$ was equal to that. I think that I'm not suppose to now that, because that series for $\cosh(x)$ isn't anywhere in my book.

Comment: I saw the answer on the book, and it used $\e^x$ and $\e^-x$, but I don't understand it.

Comment: @davidllerenav use the exponential form of the $\cosh$ function.

Comment: I have no idea of how the exponentiall form of $\cosh$ is, as I said, in my book there is almost no information about $\cosh$, there is only the graph.

Comment: cosh($x$)=$(e^x+e^{-x})/2$

Comment: In general we can write $$\sum_{n=0}^N a_{2n}=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^{2N} (1+(-1)^n)a_n$$Setting $a_n=\frac1{n!}$ and letting $N\to \infty$, we find that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(2n)!}=\frac12\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\right)=\frac12(e+e^{-1})$$

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how we went from $1+(-1)^n$ to $2$?

Comment: Only note that, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}x^{n}(1+(-1)^n)}=x^{0}(1+1)+x^{1}(1-1)+\frac{1}{2!}x^{2}(1+1)+\frac{1}{3!}x^{3}(1+(-1)^3)+\ldots$  
        $=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{2}{(2n)!}x^{2n}}$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that for any $x \in \Bbb R$ the Taylor series expansion of $e^x$ about $x=0$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^n} {n!}.$$ Note that $$\begin{align} e+e^{-1} & = 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {1} {(2n)!} \\ \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {1} {(2n)!} & = \frac {e+e^{-1}} {2} =\cosh (1). \end{align}$$

For the second one observe that $$\begin{align} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {n} {2^n} & = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {n} {2^n} \\ & = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {2^n} + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {1} {2^n} + \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac {1} {2^n} + \cdots \\ & = 1 + \frac 1 2 + \frac {1} {2^2} + \cdots \\ & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {1} {2^n} \\ & = \frac {1} {1 - \frac 1 2} \\ & = 2. \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

For the second sum, $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
$$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n$$
For $x=\frac{1}{2}$, $$\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{(1-\frac{1}{2})^2}=2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}$$

Comment: You multiplied $f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ by x, right? That's why we end up with $\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n$?

Comment: @davidllerenav Yep, the crucial step is taking the derivative in order to get the $n$ term as a coefficient in the power series.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I understand that.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem :
$$\cos x = 1- \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}......$$
Put the value of $x$ as $i$ to get:
$$\cos (ix) = 1- \frac{(ix)^2}{2!} + \frac{(ix)^4}{4!}-\frac{(ix)^6}{6!}......$$
Solve further to get:
$$\cos (ix) = 1+ \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}......$$
Put the value of $x=1$ to get
$$\cos i = 1+ \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{6!}......=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \ \frac{1}{(2n)!}$$
The second series is an arithmetico geometric series with the $n^{th}$ term as:
$$T_n=\frac{n}{2^n}$$ when you calculate the sum(start the sum from n=1 as it wont matter):
$$S_{\infty}= \frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2^2}+\frac{3}{2^3}+\frac{4}{2^4}.....$$
You can see that the numerators are in AP where as the fractions are in GP.
Just multiply the above expression with the common ratio i.e. $\frac{1}{2}$ to get
$$\frac{1}{2}S_{\infty}=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{2}{2^3}+\frac{3}{2^4}+\frac{4}{2^5}...$$
Subtract both of these equations to get :
$$\frac{1}{2}S_{\infty} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^4}...$$
Use the formula for infinite GP in the RHS to get :
$$\frac{1}{2}S_{\infty} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}$$
You will get $S_{\infty}=2$.

PS: In the first summation you can also use $\cos hx$ instead of $\cos ix$ because:
$$\cos hx = \cos ix = \frac{e^{i.(ix)}+e^{-i.(ix)}}{2}=\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}$$
Hope this helps .....